# How to replace deprecated Android "Context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration" in Xamarin.Form project?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using this Android API Context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(Configuration, DisplayMetrics), but it's deprecated, so it doesn't work in higher version of Android system. I've done research online but found only Java solutions, I'm not able to translate that into C# in my Xamarin.Form project.

Google doc says it's updated to Context.CreateConfigurationContext(Configuration), but this doesn't work for me (of course, the DisplayMetrics is not even evolved).

```
    public void SetStandardFontSize()
    {
        Configuration configuration = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.Configuration;
        configuration.FontScale = (float)1;
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        (MainActivity.mainContext as MainActivity).WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
        metrics.ScaledDensity = configuration.FontScale * metrics.Density;

        //deprecated
        Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);   
    }
```

I just want to use the above function (learned from stackoverflow post) to overwrite user custom setting of fontsize in the Android system.
So I'm looking for a correct way of updating configuration that is compatible with Android systems of all versions.

Thank you very much.

PS:
Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.SetTo(metrics); Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.Configuration.SetTo(configuration);
This works only up to Android 6, same as the deprecated function.

Comment: Do you want me to give you a detialed answer for this?

Comment: @G.hakim I tried Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.SetTo(metrics); Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.Configuration.SetTo(configuration); But it still works only up to Android 6, same as the deprecated function. So any other solution and detailed codes would be really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why, but it just worked this way,

```
    protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
    {
        Configuration overrideConfiguration = new Configuration();
        overrideConfiguration = @base.Resources.Configuration;
        overrideConfiguration.SetToDefaults();
        Context context = @base.CreateConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration);
        base.AttachBaseContext(context);
    }

    public override Resources Resources
    {
        get
        {
            Resources res = base.Resources;
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.SetToDefaults();

            res.UpdateConfiguration(config, res.DisplayMetrics);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

I hope maybe someone can explain for me, but more importantly, I hope it's useful to others as reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check Android version and execute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows#runtime-checks-for-android-versions

```
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
    // Do things the Lollipop way
}
else
{
    // Do things the pre-Lollipop way
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think 'DisplayMetrics.SetTo(metrics)' and 'Configuration.SetTo(configuration)' can fit into the "else" part, however what shall put into the "if" part, which is for version higher than Lollipop?

Comment: @solidcomer I am not that much into your particular problem, but you need to see from which version the API is deprecated, adjust that if accordingly, put deprecated API in if and new one in else.

Comment: I got the point! But on the other hand, will higher version API work in lower version systems where the deprecated API still apply? Besides, I'm still working on find the way of replacing Context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: That’s the point of if, it won’t be ever executed. So it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BaseContext.CreateConfigurationContext(configuration);
BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.SetTo(metrics);
```